# Why does the color contrast of the image on my screen change after putting on 3d-glasses and then turning my head around the for/backward axis?

Tags: visible-light, polarization

One upon a night, while looking at the physics SE site, I put on, by accident, a pair of 3-d glasses. I discovered that if I turned my head around the for/backward-axis of my head, from left to the right, the contrast of the color changed from low to high.

Any suggestions or an answer(s) to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LCD monitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display) emit polarized light because they use polarization filtering to control the amount of light passing through each pixel.

Common 3D glasses also just are two polarizers stuck into a frame. So when you're tilting your head, you're changing the angle of the polarization of your glasses against the angle of the light from the LCD, thereby in- or decreasing the intensity of light from the display actually making it to your eyes.